# Linux: what's a fast way to find all duplicate files in a directory?

Tags: linux, duplicates, diff

I have a directory with many subdirs and about 7000+ files in total. What I need to find all duplicates of all files. For any given file, its duplicates might be scattered around various subdirs and may or may not have the same file name. A duplicate is a file that you get a 0 return code from the `diff` command.

The simplest thing to do is to run a double loop over all the files in the directory tree. But that's 7000^2 sequential diffs and not very efficient:

```
for f in `find /path/to/root/folder -type f`
do
   for g in `find /path/to/root/folder -type f`
   do
        if [ "$f" = "$g" ]
        then
           continue
        fi
        diff "$f" "$g" > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
           echo "$f" MATCHES "$g"
        fi
   done
done
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Create a checksum of each file, look for duplicate checksums, then check them specifically.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277697/whats-the-quickest-way-to-find-duplicated-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian 11:

```
% mkdir files; (cd files; echo "one" > 1; echo "two" > 2a; cp 2a 2b)
% find files/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | tee listing.txt | \
    awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1 {print $2}' > dups.txt
% grep -f dups.txt listing.txt
c193497a1a06b2c72230e6146ff47080  files/2a
c193497a1a06b2c72230e6146ff47080  files/2b
```

- Find and print all files null terminated (`-print0`).
- Use `xargs` to `md5sum` them.
- Save a copy of the sums and filenames in "listing.txt" file.
- Grab the sum and pass to `sort` then `uniq -c` to count, saving into the "dups.txt" file.
- Use `awk` to list duplicates, then `grep` to find the sum and filename.